# Google Spreadsheet, filter doesn't allow wildcards? How to countif multiple columns with wildcards?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, wildcard

When I do:

```
B         C
223 herp
223 herp
3   herp
223 derp
223 herp,derp

=countif(C:C, "*herp*")
```

I correctly get 4.

When I do

```
=count(filter(B:B, B:B=223, C:C="*herp*"))
```

I incorrectly get 0.  When I remove the "*" wildcard characters, I get 2, which is better, but doesn't get herp,derp.

Does filter not support wildcard characters?  If so, how can I count a row only if two of it's columns meet two different criteria which have wildcards?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

FILTER doesn't support wildcards, no. You need to do something like:

`=COUNT(FILTER(B:B,B:B=223,SEARCH("herp",C:C)))`

or

`=COUNT(FILTER(B:B,B:B=223,REGEXMATCH(C:C,"herp")))`

Alternatively, in the [new version of Sheets](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/spreadsheets/2TNrpc9xExY), COUNTIFS is supported:

`=COUNTIFS(B:B,223,C:C,"*herp*")`

Comment: upgrading google spreadsheet seemed the easiest (at least one of the non-upgraded answers gave me a 1 even if there was no result)

Comment: Were you using COUNT or COUNTA? If there are no results from the FILTER, it returns a N/A error, and COUNTA counts this as one. So if using COUNTA, you need to wrap the FILTER in IFERROR( ).