# Google sheet query / filter with columns not Blank

Tags: google-sheets

I'am working on some document which get data from Non Google form, and the output is 36 column but there will be always filled up 8 max 9 columns with empty columns in between, with our Form we CANT change way how data are outputed. Empty column are here cuz Client fill up specific type of order so data are put in specific column.

i need query for pulling data from the main sheet and output just specific 5 specific column ( those will be always in same place ), and 2 columns that can be anywhere in between.

writing down every single column is not perfect as i need to pull data row by row not all at once ( i will be adding data in between final query output) and with that it would drasticly slow down file with few hundreds inputs added per week.

I didnt found working way to combine filter and query together to do this job ( removing empty columns [ <>'' and is not null].

Could someone help me with this ?

providing link for file : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SDR939yUSq9trLcxBid9AQeZUn-lNNiRr7O7pDiu888/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell M1 of your sheet 'Desired output' try entering this little monster

```
=Arrayformula(query({'Raw data'!A:Z\
{"Configurable list"; 'Raw data'!D2:D&'Raw data'!F2:F&'Raw data'!H2:H&'Raw data'!J2:J&'Raw data'!L2:L&'Raw data'!P2:P&'Raw data'!R2:R&'Raw data'!T2:T&'Raw data'!V2:V}\
{"Date"; ('Raw data'!E2:E&'Raw data'!G2:G&'Raw data'!I2:I&'Raw data'!M2:M&'Raw data'!O2:O&'Raw data'!Q2:Q&'Raw data'!S2:S&'Raw data'!U2:U&'Raw data'!W2:W)+0}}; 
"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col26, Col28, Col24, Col27 Where Col1 is not null format (Col28) 'dd.mm.yyyy'"))
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: This Monster sure worked as intended :D Thank you very much.  I hope i will not have any problems in future, troubleshooting would be fun then :D

Comment: Well, it looks more difficult than it really is. Three elements are constructing an array: the original data, then an extra column, which is the concatenation of the columns 'configurable list' and a third column is added which is the concatenation of the columns with dates. :-)

Comment: Ah now i understand it little bit better :) thank you

Comment: @JPV think you could take a look at my problem? Trying to exclude blank cells in my QUERY formula, but neither "is not null" is working nor !='' is working. Here's my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71085494/countifs-w-multiple-criteria-in-same-column/71087115#71087115

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is really in the heading. You can use `=filter([Range], [Range]<>"")` for each row to get to this in the desired output. The filter function is perfect for this application.

UPDATE:
Looked at your sheet to get a better view of the problem. You'll need some wildcard workaround as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342622/google-spreadsheet-filter-doesnt-allow-wildcards-how-to-countif-multiple-colu) as a second criteria to identify the Date & Configurable cells: `=filter([Range], [Range]<>"", search("Date", [Top row]))`

Comment: Sorry didnt make it work that way :/ thank you for your answer.