# Why doesn't ASTERISK work in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've had this problem since I've started using this computer and I've been able to work around it until not, but it's really annoying not being able to use such a simple and common function for my formulas.

Doesn't anyone know why the Asterisk doesn't work when used in functions? In the filter I'm using it to exclude rows (B)that have empty cells.

```
=filter({$A$2:$C},$A$2:$A=F9,$B$2:$B="*"))
```

I've googled everything and I can't seem to find anyone that's had the same issue as me.
The picture shows the formula without excluding blank cells in the 2nd row.

```
=filter({$A$2:$C},$A$2:$A=F9))
```

Or is there another way to achieve this without using the Asterisk?
Thanks for the help...[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Spreadsheet, filter doesn't allow wildcards? How to countif multiple columns with wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342622/google-spreadsheet-filter-doesnt-allow-wildcards-how-to-countif-multiple-colu)

Comment: Well here's the entire code. It has duplicates so I need to find the unique values
'''
=ifna(rows(unique(filter( {$A$2:$C},$A$2:$A=F3))),0)
'''
Right now it's filtering, Then finding the Unique, Then counting the number of rows.

Comment: Which cell is this formula applied to? What is in columns A,C,F. Please give usable info. Share a test sheet or a usable image having columns and rows shown.

Comment: Can you please share a sanitized Spreadsheet example?

Comment: Here's the sample spreadsheet. I need it to only count cells with the Barcode AND location.  (excluding "Out of Range")
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hLvbJL_21WWSsaEfBWj2XgKJAqlB6eIO6MwBFJAGmmI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `<> ""` to filter out empty cells:

```
=ifna(rows(unique(filter( {$A$2:$C},$A$2:$A=F2,$B$2:$B<>""))),0)
```

Or place this in the header cell (`H1`) and remove everything below. The column will be populated with the data you need.

```
={
  "Barcode+Location";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      F2:F = "",
        "",
        IFNA(
          VLOOKUP(
            F2:F,
            QUERY(
              UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:C, A2:A <> "", B2:B <> "")),
              "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1)
               GROUP BY Col1
               LABEL Col1 '',
                     COUNT(Col1) ''",
              0
            ),
            2,
            0
          ),
          0
        )
    )
  )
}
```

See sheet **kishkin**.

[image]